# Dictionary within a list using Counter

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I wanted to write a function which lists the Counter of dictionary items that appear for at least the number of times df in all other dictionaries.

example:

```
prune(([{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 1}, {'c': 1}], min_df=2)
[Counter({'a': 1}), Counter({'a': 1})]
prune(([{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 2}, {'c': 1}], min_df=2)
[Counter({'a': 1}), Counter({'a': 2})]
```

As we can see that 'a' occurs twice in two dictionaries it gets listed in the output.

My approach:

```
from collections import Counter
def prune(dicto,df=2):
   new = Counter()
   for d in dicto:
       new += Counter(d.keys())
   x = {}
   for key,value in new.items():
       if value >= df:
           x[key] = value
   print Counter(x)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'a': 2})
```

This gives the output as a combined Counter. As we can see, term 'a' appears 2 times on the whole and hence it satisfies the df condition and gets listed in the output. Now, Can anyone correct me to get the desired output.

Comment: In your expected output you have *two* counters. What does each counter signify? Why is having just the one counter not useful?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think OP wants to list the key value pairs that appear in every dictionary, such that each printed key appears in at least `df` many dictionaries

Comment: these two dictionaries are like two different documents with word counts in tat specific document

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I'd like the OP to make that explicit, rather than have us guess.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: normally, I'd agree with you (and would have directed my clarification at OP), but I have a feeling that OP's first language is not English and thought this would help

Comment: @Wolf:  How is this useful?  You do realize that all of your counters will have a `1` for every value in it...so they're more like sets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest:

```
from collections import Counter
def prune(dicto, min_df=2):
    # Create all counters
    counters = [Counter(d.keys()) for d in dicto]

    # Sum all counters
    total = sum(counters, Counter()) 

    # Create set with keys of high frequency
    keys = set(k for k, v in total.items() if v >= min_df)

    # Reconstruct counters using high frequency keys
    counters = (Counter({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in keys}) for d in dicto)

    # With filter(None, ...) we take only the non empty counters.
    return filter(None, counters)
```

Result:

```
>>> prune(([{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 1}, {'c': 1}], min_df=2)
[Counter({'a': 1}), Counter({'a': 1})]
```

Comment: You should make counters a generator expression if you are going to filter it.

Answer (score 1):

chain the keys and keep the keys from each dict that satisfy the condition.

```
from itertools import chain

def prune(l, min_df=0):
    # count how many times every key appears
    count = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
    # create Counter dicts using keys that appear at least  min_df times
    return filter(None,(Counter(k for k in d if count.get(k) >= min_df) for d in l))

In [14]: prune([{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 1}, {'c': 1}], min_df=2)
Out[14]: [Counter({'a': 1}), Counter({'a': 1})]
```

You can avoid the filter but I am not sure it will be any more efficient:

```
def prune(l, min_df=0):
        count = Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))
        res = []
        for d in l:
            cn = Counter(k for k in d if count.get(k) >= min_df)
            if cn:
                res.append(cn)
        return res
```

The loop is pretty much on a par:

```
In [31]: d = [{'a': 1, 'b': 10}, {'a': 1}, {'c': 1}]    
In [32]: d = [choice(d) for _ in range(1000)]   
In [33]: timeit chain_prune_loop(d, min_df=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.49 ms per loop    
In [34]: timeit prune(d, min_df=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 11.5 ms per loop
In [35]: timeit set_prune(d, min_df=2)
100 loops, best of 3: 13.5 ms per loop
```

Comment: @Shashank, yes, I was  originally doing something differently, forgot to remove the generator expression

Answer (score 0):

This will print out all the values of each key that appears in at least `df` dictionaries.

```
def prune(dicts, df):
    counts = {}
    for d in dicts:  # for each dictionary
        for k,v in d.items():  # for each key,value pair in the dictionary
            if k not in counts:  # if we haven't seen this key before
                counts[k] = []
            counts[k].append(v)  # append this value to this key

    for k,vals in counts.items():
        if len(vals) < df:
            continue  # take only the keys that have at least `df` values (that appear in at least `df` dictionaries)
        for val in vals:
            print(k, ":", val)
```